# Bookmarklet to share articles

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a [bookmarklet for my website](http://www.fineconomy.com) to share articles automatically on my plattform. The problem is it does not submit the article.

[image]

```
<div style="margin-left: 15px;"><span class="bookmarklet"><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span> Get the
    <br>
    <a title="Drag this link to your bookmark bar. Click the bookmark when you want to submit an article." data-original-title="" class="has-tooltip" onclick="return false;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Drag this link to your bookmark bar. Click the bookmark when you want to submit an article." href="javascript:location.href='http://www.fineconomy.com/submit-articles/?link='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)" style="cursor:move;text-decoration:none;">FinEco Bookmarklet</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I created a test user:

**User Name:** test

**Pwd:** test12345

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE 1**

I added the following javascript to the bottom of the page.

```
;(function(win, $) {
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('submit-articles') > -1) { 
    $(".maincontent").addClass('content-push-sidebar');
 } 
})(window, window.jQuery);
```

Furthermore, I updated the bookmarklet:

```
<span class="bookmarklet"><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span> Get the<br>
<a title="Drag this link to your bookmark bar. Click the bookmark when you want to submit an article." data-original-title="" class="has-tooltip" onclick="return false;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Drag this link to your bookmark bar. Click the bookmark when you want to submit an article." href="javascript:location.href='http://www.fineconomy.com/submit-articles/?link='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)" style="cursor:move;text-decoration:none;">FinEco Bookmarklet</a></span>
```

My, problem is that I cannot add topics to the field.

[image]

When I close the `submit-article` window the field with the topics pops up:

[image]

Any suggestions why the field is hidden?

Comment: *"The problem is it does not submit the article"* What does this mean? Your script simply redirects the browser to your `submit-articles` url, using a GET. Are you expecting something else?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thx for your answer! I basically expect that the user has pre-filled out the submit page, so that he just has to add some tags. Currently, I get nothing like that.

Comment: So, that would all depend on how that `submit-articles` endpoint is coded. This question needs a lot more information before it would be answerable.

Comment: Basically, from the logic I posted above it "should" work. What infos would you further need. I am happy to provide it asap.

Comment: What is the URL for that page shown in the second screenshot? And can you copy and paste that same URL into a different browser and get the same result? If not, then there's something going on with the code on that page (be it server-side or client-side) that is causing the issue.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thx for your reply! I tried it out with google chrome(before firefox) and I get the same result. I guess the problem has to be client sided, because I just want to load the title and the page url inside my form. (submitting is done by the user itself!) What do you think  is causing the issue?

Comment: No idea; you need to provide the code that takes the query string parameters and puts the data into the form.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan When trying to open the link like the following `http://fineconomy.com/submit-article` the submit field just pops up and then disappears. However, when pressing the submit button, the field stays up. Please use the login details above, to see the same result

Comment: SO questions should have all code necessary to answer the question, in the question itself. I'm afraid I've already spent too much time on this question already.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I provided everything that should help! Even some login details. However, the real problem is that neither you or I do not understand what the real problem is. Still, thx for your support!

Comment: You need to do something with the query strings.  If I navigate to http://fineconomy.com/submit-articles/?link=http://www.google.com&title=thegoogle nothing happens.  You need to handle the query strings on the article submission page so that the form fields are populated.  The problem you have is separate from the bookmarklet.

Comment: @AdamKonieska Basically the `submit-article` field pops extremely shortly up, but does not stay visible to the user. THe field should get populated from the bookmarklet.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I fixed the bookmarklet, but the Topics field is not loading properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mrquad the field not displaying correctly, and not populating the fields are *separate* from the bookmarklet.  You need to show us your code thats handing the query string variables.  Accessing the URL with those query string parameters should fill the article, regardless if it came from the bookmarklet or was accessed directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restating the question to make sure I understand:

You want a bookmarklet that, when clicked, will take a user to fineconomy and pre-fill an article submission form with the url and title of whatever webpage the user happened to be on.

Upon arriving at fineconomy, the snippet you added gets the form to appear by checking to see if the page url (on fineconomy) contains "submit-articles" and, if it does, essentially adds a class to the main content div to make the form appear.

Because you check to see if you are on the http://fineconomy.com/submit-articles/ page, I assume you are working in some sort of templating system that only lets you add scripts to some kind of global footer--perhaps wordpress, if the wp-theme references.

Anyway, I think **the reason the topics field is hidden** is that there is this css declaration:

```
/* NEW CODE FOR V1.1 */

/** SNIP **/

.selectize-input{
    display:none;
}
```

The topics field is a `.selectize-input` field. I'm not sure why the style is there, but it's preventing the field from displaying.  I don't know enough about your system to say whether or not that declaration belongs there.

If it does belong there, I suppose you'll have to augment the javascript snippet on the page to display the component, as well. Something like this:

```
;(function(win, $) {
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('submit-articles') > -1) { 
    $(".maincontent").addClass('content-push-sidebar');
    $(".selectize-input").show();
 } 
})(window, window.jQuery);
```

Although, you say the field appears when the form gets dismissed, which can happen if something is trying to toggle its visibility `$(".selectize-input").toggle();`.  This would suggest that the submission form is usually displayed via some kind of method call, and, if this is the case, it would really be advisable to use this call, rather than adding the `content-push-sidebar` class in the snippet above.

If possible, I'd also check if there's a way to put the snippet on the submit-page only, negating the need to check the current url for "submit-article". It would generally make things easier to maintain, less error prone, and more efficient.

Comment: I'll also note that the bookmarklet, itself, does not provide the topics, like it does with the url and title of the initial page (when it was clicked).  I don't think you were looking for that, though.  If you wanted to, though, you could look for some specific words in the provided url / title to fill in suggested topics (i.e. if "venture" is in the title or url, you could add "startup" to the topics).  This might require more control than you have, though, depending on the system in use.